# designing a game in python where random mathematical problems appear for the user to solve

Tags: python, random

1. The code is supposed to generate random equations for the user to answer with `num1` being in the range of 1 to 9 while `num2` in the range 0,10
2. The user starts with 100 points
3. if user enters `x` the program terminates
4. if user enter wrong answer the score decreases by 10
5. if user enters correct answer the score increases by 9

I've been successful in doing steps one to 3 however when it comes to checking if the inputted answer by the user is correct it always returns it as wrong even if its correct example
[image: figure1]

I assume this is because my code doesn't evaluate the question and been trying to figure out why

```
import random


# set variables
score = 100  # score of user
operator = ["+", "-", "*", "/"] #operators
number_1 = random.randint(1, 9)  # this variable will be a random number between 1 and 9
number_2 = random.randint(0, 10)  # this variable will be a random number between 0 and 10


# this function prints the dashes
def dash():
    print("-" * 50)

while score >= 0 and score <= 200:
    dash()
    print("You currently hold: ", score, " points")
    print("Get more than 200 points you win, under 0 you lose")

    sign = random.choice(operator)  # chooses random operator
    real_answer = number_1,sign,number_2

    print(str(number_1) + str(sign) + str(number_2), "?")
    dash()
    print("Press x to close program")
    answer = input("Enter your guess of number: ")

    if answer == "x":
        print("Program has been terminated properly")
        break
    elif answer == real_answer:
        score = score + 9
        continue
    elif answer  != real_answer:
        score = score - 10
        continue

if score < 0:
        print("Unlucky, You lost")

elif score > 200:
    print("CONGRATULATIONS YOU WON")
```

Comment: answer is a string, needs to get converted to an integer or the comparison will always fail.

Comment: `real_answer` is a tuple containing the integer `number_1`, the string `sign`, and the integer `number_2`. It is not the result of applying the operator in `sign` to the two numbers. Even if you convert your `answer` to an integer, it will never be equal to the _tuple_ `(number_1, sign, number_2)` because an integer can not be equal to a tuple.

Comment: Also your code will only pick a new `sign` every time, and keep the two operands the same. You will start repeating questions before the user ever reaches 200 or zero points.

Comment: You need to do some [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and narrow down your problem. There is no need to assume why your code doesn't work, when you can debug it and find out for sure. Debugging is an absolutely essential skill for a programmer, and the sooner into your programming career you develop that ability, the easier your life will be

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that real_answer and inputted answer were different data types, this should fix it by making them both floats.

```
import random

# set variables
score = 100  # score of user
operator = ["+", "-", "*", "/"] #operators
number_1 = random.randint(1, 9)  # this variable will be a random number between 1 and 9
number_2 = random.randint(0, 10)  # this variable will be a random number between 0 and 10


# this function prints the dashes
def dash():
    print("-" * 50)

while score >= 0 and score <= 200:
    dash()
    print("You currently hold: ", score, " points")
    print("Get more than 200 points you win, under 0 you lose")

    sign = random.choice(operator)  # chooses random operator
    # make a variable called real answer equal to the answer of the equation
    if sign == "+":
        real_answer = number_1 + number_2
    elif sign == "-":
        real_answer = number_1 - number_2
    elif sign == "*":
        real_answer = number_1 * number_2
    elif sign == "/":
        real_answer = number_1 / number_2
    

    print(str(number_1) + str(sign) + str(number_2), "?")
    dash()
    print("Press x to close program")
    answer = input("Enter your guess of number: ")


    if answer == "x":
        print("Program has been terminated properly")
        break
    elif float(answer) == real_answer:
        score = score + 9
        continue
    elif float(answer)  != real_answer:
        score = score - 10
        continue

if score < 0:
        print("Unlucky, You lost")

elif score > 200:
    print("CONGRATULATIONS YOU WON")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error here is that the variable `real_answer` is not an integer, but instead a tuple. For example, 1+7 gives (1, '+', 7), instead of 8.

Their are two main fixes to this:

The first fix is to create a dictionary which can contain the functions for each symbol. It would look something like this:

```py
signs = {
    '+': (lambda a, b: a + b),
    '-': (lambda a, b: a - b),
    '*': (lambda a, b: a * b),
    '/': (lambda a, b: a // b)
}
```

Now, to call this function, you can do `real_answer = signs[sign](number_1,number_2)`. Essentially, this calls the function from the dictionary depending on what the sign is. If the sign is `/` the code recognises that divide means `lambda a, b: a // b` and calls this function with `number_1` and `number_2`

The other, but slightly more messy verisio is to use `eval`. What eval does is runs a string as code. For example, you could do:

```py
real_answer = eval(f"{number_1}{sign}{number_2)")
```

While this does work, eval is generally not the best method.

The last thing to point out is that you don't cast your answer variables to an integer. When comparing numbers in your if statements, you want to use `int(answer)` to make sure you're using the integer version of your answer.

The full code should look something like this:

```py
import random


# set variables
score = 100  # score of user
operator = ["+", "-", "*", "/"] #operators
number_1 = random.randint(1, 9)  # this variable will be a random number between 1 and 9
number_2 = random.randint(0, 10)  # this variable will be a random number between 0 and 10

signs = {
    '+': (lambda a, b: a + b),
    '-': (lambda a, b: a - b),
    '*': (lambda a, b: a * b),
    '/': (lambda a, b: a // b)
}

# this function prints the dashes
def dash():
    print("-" * 50)

while score >= 0 and score <= 200:
    dash()
    print("You currently hold: ", score, " points")
    print("Get more than 200 points you win, under 0 you lose")

    sign = random.choice(operator)  # chooses random operator
    real_answer = signs[sign](number_1,number_2)

    print(str(number_1) + str(sign) + str(number_2), "?")
    dash()
    print("Press x to close program")
    answer = input("Enter your guess of number: ")

    if answer == "x":
        print("Program has been terminated properly")
        break
    elif int(answer) == real_answer:
        score = score + 9
        continue
    elif int(answer)  != real_answer:
        score = score - 10
        continue

if score < 0:
        print("Unlucky, You lost")

elif score > 200:
    print("CONGRATULATIONS YOU WON")
```